# Access Denied on NVIDIA GRID 7.2 Driver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nvidia, grid

I am trying to set up an NVIDIA Tesla T4 GPU and use its RTX functionality in a raytracing application (Bakery for Unity3D). But every time I launch the app, Bakery tells me it could not find the OptiX library.

I believe to have tracked it down to the driver version being too old (412.16), but when I try to load the GRID 7.2 drivers from the [NVIDIA drivers public storage bucket](https://storage.googleapis.com/nvidia-drivers-eu-public/) I get an access denied exception.

Do I need to ask for special authorization to get access to this driver?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. This page will describe that you need a license.
[NVIDIA vGPU Software (Quadro vDWS, GRID vPC, GRID vApps)](https://www.nvidia.com/object/vGPU-software-driver.html)

This page, I've set it for the T4 license section depending on what you are looking for.
[NVIDIA® Virtual GPU (vGPU) Software Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/grid/7.0/grid-vgpu-user-guide/index.html#vgpu-types-tesla-t4)

If you aren't paying for a vGPU license, you can start a 
[90 Day Free Trial](https://www.nvidia.com/object/nvidia-enterprise-account.html) here.

Comment: Thanks for the info, you don't happen to know why the Google Cloud Storage bucket doesn't let me access the latest drivers? I expect Google to have the corresponding license for their Nvidia GPUs and set up this repository for their users to download them. I can download an older driver, but not the latest ones.